# Problems with postgreSQL on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: postgresql

I am a new postgresql user and I am trying to open an new account on this

database technology. As I was trying to open a new server  I cannot create a database within this server. It says an error when I try to open that up.

Could you please tell whats wrong with this.

I do the following steps.

**I create an account as this:**
[image]

Despite this the server does not get created.
Is there something wrong with configuration of this server.
This is the error which says [image]
Thank you in advance

Vangjush

Comment: That's a link to an image file on your own machine.

Comment: Sorry, just edit the question .

Comment: I use the local IP , I get if I run ifconfig on terminal

Comment: Is it really necessary to post an image of your entire screen both times? You could crop the image to just the relevant portion in the first one (about 1/4 of what you included), and just capture the error message window in the second. Both would make the images much smaller for us to download, keep them from being reduced so much in order to be displayed, and make them so they're more readable when we try and undderstand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is not the IP address of the server: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html

I'm no expert, but I believe the service is a shorthand for specifying other connection parameters. It's most simple to establish connections at first by specifying the values directly, so just leave that blank.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/libpq-pgservice.html